# Testing failure of an assignment with unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, properties, variable-assignment, assertraises

One of my attributes is a property where the setter calls a validation function that raises an exception if the new value is invalid:

```
pos.offset = 0
# @offset.setter calls validate(offset=0)
# PositionError: Offset may not be 0.
```

I'm trying to add a test to ensure that this fails. However, I can't figure out how to get assertRaises to work with an assignment.

The normal syntax of assertRaises requires a method, not an attribute/property:

```
self.assertRaises(PositionError, pos.offset, 0)
# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

The other forms I've tried are invalid Python:

```
self.assertRaises(PositionError, pos.offset = 0)
# SyntaxError: Keyword can't be an expression
self.assertRaises(PositionError, lambda: pos.offset = 0)
# SyntaxError: lambda cannot contain assignment
```

**How do I test failure of assignment to a property?**

*Note: Python 2.6, I know unittest has some new features in 2.7*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you want to use `unittest` to test that an exception occurs in a block of code rather than just a function call, you can use `assertRaises` as a context manager:

```
with self.assertRaises(PositionError):
    pos.offset = 0
```

This use can be found in the [unittest docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.html#basic-example).

While this is not available in Python 2.6, and won't work for you as such (I just saw your note), I think it's worth including among the answers, as it's probably the clearer way to do this for python 2.7+.

Answer (score 8):

**Before Python 2.7,** you want to use `setattr(object, name, value)` [(*doc*)](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr). This allows you to set a value to an attribute.

```
self.assertRaises(PositionError, setattr, pos, "offset", 0)
# ... ok
```

This should always work, because if the attribute is a property and thus "secretly" calls a function, it must be within a class. I don't think a standard assignment can fail (although an *expression* on the right side can fail, i.e. `x = 1/0`).

Comment: Assignment can fail for a variety of reasons (say, adding an attribute which isn't in `__slots__`), even if you don't have a descriptor, but this is the correct answer otherwise.